# How to get the bot's guilds without being rate limited?

Tags: express, discord, fetch-api

**Problem:**
I'm trying to use discord's v10 api, but I always get rate limited

The endpoint that gets fetched at reload is `api/v10/users/@me/guilds`, which has a limit so after some reloads, I get rate limited.

**Code**:

```
const BotGuilds = await fetch(
            `https://discord.com/api/v10/users/@me/guilds`,
            {
                method: 'GET',
                credentials: 'include',
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bot ' + DiscordConfiguration.Token,
                },
            }
        ).then((res) => res.json());
```

**Solution:**
Saving the guilds then reloading whenever the bot joins a guild.

***(Thanks to @mousetail)***

Comment: So.... wait a bit longer between reloads?

Comment: @mousetail, the website must be used by a lot of people at the same time, do you think that won't hit the rate limit easily?

Comment: You will need to share a lot more context. The code here will run into the rate limit if it's callled to often. Right now the only context you have given is it is called "on reload" but when does a reload happen? Is this server code or client code, or part of a bot?

Comment: @mousetail, Whenever someone opens the website, a request to Discord's api is sent to get the guilds, after some tries, I get rate limited. Anything else?

Comment: Well if people request the web page more often than your rate limit you shouldn't call the API endpoint every time someone uses the endpoint. Does the value really change that often? Maybe you can save it and reload it only once in a while.

Comment: @mousetail I guess saving them then reloading when the bot joins a guild would work, thanks.